# How to render all of a page's children's content in a confluence macro

Tags: java, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to build a simple confluence macro that renders all of the child pages of the current parent. Essentially a cross between the existing macros: children display, and include page. I did take a look at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/confluence-advanced-macros-plugin/src) for those macros, but since this is my first time developing in confluence, it was more confusing than helpful.

Right now I am working on the execute method, and since I am new to confluence development I am not sure 100% what exactly needs to go there.

I already read through [Atlassian's Guide to Making a new Confluence Macro](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/tutorials/macro-tutorials-for-confluence/creating-a-new-confluence-macro)
but it seems they just used html to wrap a list of properties of existing macros.

So I decided to look at the [API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/confluence/latest/reference/packages.html), specifically [Page](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/confluence/latest/reference/com/atlassian/confluence/pages/Page.html#getLinkWikiMarkup())
I was able to get very close, the problem is, when I copy the page's bodies over I don't get the children's macros and styles that are in their pages.

```
    @Override
    public String execute(Map<String, String> parameters, String body,
            ConversionContext context) throws MacroExecutionException {
        //loop through each child page and get its content
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ContentEntityObject ceo = context.getPageContext().getEntity();
        Page parent =(Page) ceo ;
        List<Page> children = parent.getChildren();

        for(Page child:children)

        {
          sb.append(child.getBodyAsString());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

How do I get all of it not just the text?

Also I am tagging this with java since that is what the plugins are written in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There we go I figured it out.

I needed to convert it from storage format to a view format for it to render the macros as well.

```
{

  String converted = xhtmlUtils.convertStorageToView(child.getBodyAsString(), context);
  sb.append(converted);

}
```

xhtmlUtils was initialized in the constructor if you were following the tutorial

```
private final XhtmlContent xhtmlUtils;

public ExampleMacro(XhtmlContent xhtmlUtils) 
{
    this.xhtmlUtils = xhtmlUtils;   
}
```

I also added annotations as per a suggestion at [Atlassian answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12286125)

```
@RequiresFormat(Format.Storage)
public String execute(Map<String, String> params, String body, ConversionContext conversionContext) throws MacroExecutionException {
```

where Format and RequiresFormat are these classes/annotations

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.macro.annotation.Format;
import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.macro.annotation.RequiresFormat
```